# AWS Cloud9 environment creation for Ruby on Rails tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial (Hartl, Michael).

When I execute the `rvm install 3.1.2` command in my newly created AWS Cloud9 environment I receive the following error message:

> This is taking longer than expected. The delay may be caused by high CPU usage in your environment, your T2 or T3 instance might be running out of burstable CPU capacity credits, or there are VPC configuration issues. Please check the VPC settings or the troubleshooting documentation for help with these issues.

I tried to follow the received instructions to check the VPC settings. I checked also the AWS troubleshooting documentation.